# Is there any way to add an user to a Group Policy without specifying the location?

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

I am using Windows 7 Enterprise.

Is there any way to add an user to a Group Policy without specifying the location?

If I understood it properly, It seems that when you add an user using the Group Policy Manager Editor, it searches for the name and adds the location as a prefix of the name automatically. For example:

My-Computer/MyUser or Workgroup/MyGroup

I supose that it is not the same to add an user with the location specified for one place or another. For example, If MyUser has a prefix of My-Computer, the rules won't be applied for the Workgroup.

Becuase of that, I was wondering if there is anyway to specify it for a general location. I mean, I would like to have the same as in the default setup, where there is only "Administrator" in the policies without any kind of prefix.